# Ext-JS QuickTips not working correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs, validation

I'm trying to implement one of Saki's [examples](http://examples.extjs.eu/) in `Form --> Displaying Form Submit Errors`, but looking at the html of included classes I don't see several of the one's he uses (like theme empty.css, icons.css, extjs.ico, and Ext.us.form.XCheckbox.js). I'm using Ext-JS 3.3.0.... could anyone link me to a source that shows how to utilize QuickTips for 3.3.0?  Or a way to make sure I have all the required files?

Currently when I try to do msgTarget: 'side' the red explanation point isn't appearing like it should. Also the actual tooltip that appears isn't styled correctly. See below (I have the msgTarget: 'side' commented out for this so you can see the tooltip).

This is what my JSP's Head looks like, I can't tell if its a style sheet problem or that I am not refreshing something correctly.

```
    <!-- Include Ext and app-specific scripts: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/shared/examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/form/states.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/ux/MultiSelect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/ux/ItemSelector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/ux/fileuploadfield/FileUploadField.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../examples/ux/RowExpander.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/ux/CheckColumn.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/TreeGrid.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/Exporter-all.js"></script>

    <!-- My JS's: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/comm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/commStore.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Ext Stylesheets here: -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="../examples/ux/css/MultiSelect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../examples/ux/fileuploadfield/css/fileuploadfield.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../examples/grid/grid-examples.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/TreeGrid.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/TreeGridLevels.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="tundra"     href="../css/xtheme-tundra.css" />

    <!-- My StyleSheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="commTool" href="../css/CommTool.css" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the custom `xtheme-tundra.css` theme stylesheet and see if that helps

Comment: I tried it with just the ext-all.css style sheet, but it still didn't show up.

Comment: If I get some time I'll try to make an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, some CSS is interfering with your tooltip's style. In your code, you are using lot of css & js that are not part of the framework. Do you need them? Did you try running your application with only the default ExtJS stylesheets? Try running your application using ext-all.css alone.

Comment: cool I'll give this a try.  That's the one thing that always confused me with ext-js, I wasn't sure what all I needed to include file wise

Comment: If I just include the ext-all.css, I can see the tool-tip but its just text and a white box